# What is a "Wald test for trend?"

Tags: panel-data, terminology, trend, test-for-trend

I am reviewing a manuscript and the authors state that some results are by a "Wald test for trend". Has anyone heard of this? I hadn't, and Google revealed nothing.

I know I always say to provide details, but in this case I cannot.

Comment: Is this in the context of a vector autoregression?

Comment: Do the results relate to a "break/change" in the trend?

Comment: @ssdecontrol No, it was just an ordinary trend type of thing. Changes in a variable over time.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos No, it was just a regular trend

Comment: I believe it's a test for linear trend within levels of ordinal IVs, generally in a regression or GLM context.

Comment: Thank @Glen_b. So, it's probably OK.

Comment: I think that an early reference for the idea (in the context of contingency tables) is Yates F. (1948),
"The Analysis of Contingency Tables with Groupings Based on Quantitative Characters", *Biometrika*
Vol. **35**, No. 1/2 (May), pp. 176-181

Comment: Googling the term turns up lots of uses of "Wald test for trend". I think it gets "Wald" simply because a Wald test is applied to the coefficient of the linear term.

Comment: @Glen_b that was my thought/guess: it's a "Wald-type" test for whatever the trend might be in this case, rather than a specialized technique, in that it follows the general pattern of $\frac{(\hat{\theta}-\theta)^2}{V[\hat{\theta}]}$.

Comment: @Glen_b, why not turn that into an official answer, so that this doesn't remain unanswered?